# The asset “courses/python” is not present in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Doing a simple `Rails` project, when I try to run it on `localhost:3000`, I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "courses/python" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
 5:<div class="card">
 6:<div class="card-image">
 7:<%= link_to course do %>
 8:<%= image_tag "courses/#{course.image}" %>
 9:<% end %>
10:</div>
11:<div class="card-content">app/views/pages/home.html.erb:8app/views/pages/home.html.erb:7app/views/pages/home.html.erb:3
```

Comment: Seems like `courses/python` asset folder doesn't exist. Have you checked your path?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385685/actionviewtemplateerror-the-asset-courses-python-is-not-present-in-the-as

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your image directory in this way `app/assets/images/courses/course_image.jpg`
2. Include it in your `application.css` file like `//= require courses`
3. After that you may use it in your view like `<%= image_tag "courses/course_image.jpg" %>`

More about asset pipeline [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: #2 does nothing since this has nothing to do with css