# ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "courses/python" is not present in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a very simple Rails program, and I am facing a problem:

Error shows that  problem is at line 3

```rb
<div class="card-image">
<%= link_to course do %>
<%= image_tag "courses/#{course.image}" %>
<% end %></div><div class="card-content">
```

> The asset "courses/python" is not present in the asset pipeline.

I thought that my code was ok? Could you please give me some idea?

Comment: can you update the question with details where image python is available in your application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384885/the-asset-courses-python-is-not-present-in-the-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're missing the file extension.

Also make sure that an image is provided inside: `assets/images/courses` with the exact same name as `course.image`