# Problem with path : Error The asset “courses/python” is not present in the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a very simple rails program and trying to show a picture

Here is my code

```
<%= link_to course do %>
        <%= image_tag "courses/1.png" %>
        <% end %>
```

I put the picture `1.png` at the folder `courses` so it could be show. Very easy to understand. But when I tried to changed to another folder like this

```
<%= link_to course do %>
        <%= image_tag "images/1111.png" %>
        <% end %>
```

I can not show the picture.
Could you please give me some ideas for me with this problem? I know it is easy to understand but I am stucking with this one, please give me some ideas. Thank you very much.

Comment: If your first example works and the second one doesn't, it is most likely because your relative path to the image is wrong in the second example. Where is the images directory in relation to the view? And think about what image_tag expects.

Comment: @MarkMerritt : the path to the image is not wrong, but I just thought that the problem is the images folder is the father set of the courses folder ? Am I right ? Or maybe another problem with my way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "courses/python" is not present in the asset pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385685/actionviewtemplateerror-the-asset-courses-python-is-not-present-in-the-as)